# How to view JSON data in autocomplete in the windows8 search charm bar?

Tags: json, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

Hi I am developing one windows8 app using HTML5 and Javascript in VS 2012.

I have a requirement to provide search functionality, it is like when user search for anything in search bar the data should show in the search autocomplete. Data is available in JSON format which hits this URL "http://healthkartplus.com/webservices/search/both?name=crocin" and get the result. Please help me if somebody is aware of it.

Following is the result when I search for crocin in the search bar. I want the result data from this JSON.

```
    {"status":0,"errors":null,"op":"searching","result":[{"id":26725,"mfId":55078,"label":"Crocin (1000 mg) 40 Tablet(Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd.)","name":"Crocin (1000 mg)","type":"drugs","packSize":"40 Tablet","manufacturer":"Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd."},{"id":27050,"mfId":55078,"label":"Crocin (15 ml) 15 ml(Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd.)","name":"Crocin (15 ml)","type":"drugs","packSize":"15 ml","manufacturer":"Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd."},{"id":26696,"mfId":55078,"label":"Crocin (500 mg) 15 Tablet(Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd.)","name":"Crocin (500 mg)","type":"drugs","packSize":"15 Tablet","manufacturer":"Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd."},{"id":27014,"mfId":55078,"label":"Crocin (60 ml) 60 ml(Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd.)","name":"Crocin (60 ml)","type":"drugs","packSize":"60 ml","manufacturer":"Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd."},{"id":26780,"mfId":55078,"label":"Crocin (650 mg) 10 Tablet(Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd.)","name":"Crocin (650 mg)","type":"drugs","packSize":"10 Tablet","manufacturer":"Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd."},{"id":26933,"mfId":55078,"label":"Crocin DS (60 ml) 60 ml(Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd.)","name":"Crocin DS (60 ml)","type":"drugs","packSize":"60 ml","manufacturer":"Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd."},{"id":27035,"mfId":55078,"label":"Crocin Paed (15 ml) 15 ml(Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd.)","name":"Crocin Paed (15 ml)","type":"drugs","packSize":"15 ml","manufacturer":"Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd."},{"id":64010,"mfId":55078,"label":"Crocin Pain Relief Tab   10 x 1(Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd.)","name":"Crocin Pain Relief Tab  ","type":"drugs","packSize":"10 x 1","manufacturer":"Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd."},{"id":26733,"mfId":55078,"label":"Crocin Quik (500 mg) 10 Tablet(Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd.)","name":"Crocin Quik (500 mg)","type":"drugs","packSize":"10 Tablet","manufacturer":"Glaxo Smithkline Pharmaceuticals Ltd."}],"hasMore":false,"suggestions":[]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Search contract sample app shows how to do this.